# What are the minimum permissions required for a user to add capabilities to a TFS build agent

Tags: tfs

A user who is in the project administrators role and an administrator for the agent pool containing an existing build agent receives a permission denied message when trying to add a user defined capability to the build agent. What additional permissions do they need to be able to make this change?
They cannot be added as a TFS administrator or a collection administrator for internal security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your custom user-defined capabilities with following steps:

- Go to Agent Pools through the Settings button on top of the menu.
- Select one of the agent in your agent pool.
- Click the Capabilities tab to add your custom capabilities.

[image]

If the user is without permission to do this, you could try to add his account as the “Service Account” or “Administrator” role of the agent in the queue.

You could also give him the Administrator Role on a project agent pool. More details please take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops#security

Comment: They are already assigned as an administrator for the agent pool at the collection level containing the specific agents. At the project level they are a project administrator and that group is assigned administrator permissions to the project's agent queue.
In retrospect I did not say this is TFS on-prem and the version is 2017U2.

Comment: @jim This is weird, did this only occurs for a specific agent or all agents. Did this agent configured as Interactive or service mode?

Comment: I believe they are running as a service. I am have asked the users to run some test scenarios to see if this is an issue for all the users in this role and on all the pools they are assigned to. They're on the other side of the world so it will be a while.

Comment: The users eventually got back to me. They say it now works! I guess they were doing something wrong.